# Gitでコミット間の変更点のみを画像やテキスト形式で抽出する方法

Tags: git, git-bash

コミット間の差分を、テキスト・画像・csvなどの形式で、一覧として表示する方法を教えていただけますでしょうか。

以下のように、VSCodeを使用してcommitA/Bのdiffを取得しています。
この時、test1.txtやtest2.txtの表示をクリックすれば、、2ファイル間の差分を取得できますが、
この差分を1つのテキストファイルや画像ファイルとして、確認する方法を探しています。

[image]

[gitでcommit間の差分を出力する](https://qiita.com/kasyuu/items/bc8489831e200b641456) を参考に、git diffコマンドの使用も試みたのですが、差分が出ない部分も抽出されてしまいます。
以下のように変更点のみ抽出も可能ですが、手間も考えてgitの機能単体で抽出を行いたいです。

[image]

下記URLのように、gitでコミット間の差分を抽出する方法も見つかったのですが、差分はエクスプローラー上でしか確認できず、私の使用したい方法とは異なります。

[Gitリビジョン間の差分をエクスポート](https://www.sukerou.com/2021/03/git.html)

下記のように、git diff –name-onlyを使用する方法では、差分が見えているファイル名のみ表示されてしまい、ファイルの内容のdiff取得ができなくなってしまいます。

[Gitから変更されたファイルだけを取り出す方法](https://www.techgaku.com/export-only-changed-files-from-git-repository/)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cZIz.png)の下部に記載のように、変更点を抽出する方法があれば教えていただけないでしょうか。
何卒宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: サンプルだと非常に簡単な例 (行単位での差分) しかありませんが、行の途中の文字列で差分が出たり、"行番号" の情報も重要です。また、コミット間だと当然複数のファイルが対象になるかと思います。その辺りはどのような結果で表示されることを想定していますか？

Comment: 行の途中の文字列での差分は抽出する必要がなく、
行単位での差分を抽出したいです。

行番号情報はあるのが望ましいですが、無くても大丈夫です。

複数のファイルが対象になるため、添付画像のように、全ファイルでの変更結果を抽出して確認したいです。

Comment: `git diff`コマンドにオプション「`--unified=0`」を付ければ差分が無い行は出力されなくなると思うのですが、これでもまだ情報が多いということでしょうか？